# Все ли файлы нужно загружать на GitHub?

Tags: java, android, github

Допустим хочу выгрузить android-проект на github. Так вот возник вопрос, может и глупый, но все же. Все ли файлы и папки нужно загружать в репозиторий? Нужно ли загружать все gradle файлы/папки? Видел, что в некоторых библиотеках загружены непосредственно java-файлы, xml и манифест. Необходимо, чтобы в последующем при выгрузке с github проект нормально собирался.

Comment: вообще строгих правил нет есть только best practices, например как из ответа @Энткейщик, но в любом случае бывают исключения.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не все. Только те, которые являются файлами проекта (код, разметка и т.п.), а не служебными или конфигурационным файлами IDE, временными файлами, созданными при компиляции и т.д. Java, xml и манифест входят в проект, файлы в папках gradle, build, .idea и проч. - не входят.

Вот коллекция файлов [.gitignore для самых разных проектов](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

И [конкретно для андроида](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).

Answer (score 2):

Как правило исключаются каталоги .gradle, build и файлы *.iml, local.properties, если не используются проектные настройки (стиль кода, форматирование, копирайты и т.п.), то каталог .idea также исключается. А вообще все эти исключения должны быть описаны в .gitignore файле, что должен лежать в корне проекта. У каждого модуля должен быть свой .gitignore, как правило если проект уже под гитом, то при создании модуля в его .gitignore файл автоматом добавляется каталог build.